# Remove last dot from CSV field

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, format

A client of mine managed to change the formatting for the coordinates to `52.143.348` instead of `52.143348`. This was imported in the db for thousands of locations.

It's possible to export, and then import the corrected data again.

So what I hoped to do was the change the format of the field that holds the coordinates, or run something that always removes the last dot from the data, but in both cases I'm not sure where to start.

Would anyone have an idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the number of characters are predictable, in a new column use

```
=REPLACE(A1,7,1,"")
```

This simply removes the decimal by looking up the value (the currently incorrect coordiante, in this case `A1), reading the 7th character/position, selecting a single character and replacing it with nothing.

You can then copy this field and paste special (paste a value) in the desired location/column.

[image]

Another option is to use SUBSTITUTE

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","",2)
```

This is probably a little easier to understand in that it looks up the value (in cell `A1`), looks for the decimal, replaces it with `""` but only applies this to the second instance it finds (hence the number `2` at the end).

Both of these require you to create a new column.